# Не работает калькулятор

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Знания в данном языке крайне слабые, решил поучиться создавать окна, однако на первом же проекте, сделанном по видеоуроку, я облажался. Окно вообще не открывается и выдаёт ошибку, в комментариях решение не нашёл, а превеликий интернет мне ответа на данный вопрос не дал, даже не знаю, что делать.

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('Калькулятор')


def calc(key):
    global memory
    if key == '=':
        str1 = '+-=/*1234567890.'
        if calc_entry.get()[0] not in str1:
            calc_entry.insert(END, 'Это не число')
            messagebox.showerror('Ошибка, это не число')

        try:
            result = eval(calc_entry.get())
            calc_entry.insert(END, '=' + str(result))
        except:
            calc_entry.insert(END, 'ОШИБКА')
            messagebox.showerror('ОШИБКА', 'Проверьте правильность введёных данных')

    elif key == 'C':
        calc_entry.delete(0, END)

    elif key == '+/-':
        if '=' in calc_entry.get():
            calc_entry.delete(0, END)
            try:
                if calc_entry.get()[0] == '-':
                    calc_entry.delete(0)
                else:
                    calc_entry.insert(0, '-')
            except IndexError:
                pass
    else:
        if '=' in calc_entry.get():
            calc_entry.delete(0, END)
        calc_entry.insert(END, key)


bttn_list = [
    '7', '8', '9',
    '4', '5', '6',
    '1', '2', '3',
    '0', '  +  ',
    '-', '*', '/',
    '+/-', '  =  '
    '.', '   C   '
]
r = 1
c = 0

for i in bttn_list:
    rel = ''
    cmd = lambda x=i: calc(x)
    ttk.Button(root, text=i, command=cmd).grid(row=r, colum=c)
    c += 1
    if c > 4:
        c = 0
        r += 1

calc_entry = Entry(root, width=33)
calc_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5, )

root.mainloop()
```

Выдаёт:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/ras_saas/Rassas.py", line 58, in <module>
    ttk.Button(root, text=i, command=cmd).grid(row=r, colum=c)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2223, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: ambiguous option "-colum": must be -column, -columnspan, -in, -ipadx, -ipady, -padx, -pady, -row, -rowspan, or -sticky
```

Comment: Читаем ошибку: `_tkinter.TclError: ambiguous option "-colum": must be -column, ...` Уже тут видно, что у вас `colum` вместо `column`.

Comment: @insolor
Спасибо Вам огромное! Всё заработало!